# Can't figure out why line is not being drawn in SDL

Tags: c++, sdl

This program to draw a line in SDL is not working:

```
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("A line", 10, 10, 1200, 600, false);

    bool running = true;

    while (running)
    {
        SDL_Event events;
        if (SDL_WaitEvent(&events))
            if (events.type == SDL_QUIT)
                running = false;

        SDL_Renderer* renderer;
        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, 10, 10, 500, 500);

    }

    SDL_Quit();

    return 1;
}
```

When I run the program, I don't get any error, but nothing is drawn either.

Comment: You shouldn't create a renderer every frame.

Comment: Or leak said renderer.

Comment: I just changed the code to only create the renderer once and run it, but it still isn't drawing anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few issues:

- You're missing a [`SDL_RenderPresent()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderPresent) so nothing is ever actually drawn to the screen.
- As @tkausl points out, don't create (& leak) a SDL_Renderer every frame
- Use [`SDL_PollEvent()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent) in a loop to fully drain the event queue.
- `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor()` affects `SDL_RenderClear()` as well as `SDL_RenderDrawLine()`; as one might imagine black-on-black is kinda hard to see :)  Set a more visible color before trying to draw a line.
- Should probably be passing `a = 255` to `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor()`.

All together:

```
// g++ main.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2`
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("A line", 10, 10, 1200, 600, false);
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    bool running = true;
    while (running)
    {
        SDL_Event event;
        while( SDL_PollEvent(&event) )
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                running = false;
        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
        SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, 10, 10, 500, 500);
        SDL_RenderPresent( renderer );
    }

    SDL_Quit();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Also have one more question: Is it sufficient to call `SDL_RenderPresent( renderer );` once? or do i have to call it everytime i draw something ?

Comment: @Cool_Cornflakes: Generally you only need to call `SDL_RenderPresent()` once per frame.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working now. Just one more question: I read that waiting for events is faster than polling, so why use polling ?

Comment: `SDL_WaitEvent()` blocks the calling process if the event queue is empty, which is a problem if you have game-type logic that needs to run continuously.  `SDL_PollEvent()` is a quick and easy work-around, though you can [register a timer callback that submits a user event](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_AddTimer#Code_Examples) if you're dead-set on `SDL_WaitEvent()`.